# Strictly Upper Triangular Matrix Product s

Tags: matrices

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be matrices strictly upper triangular of order $n$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Is it possible to have $AC=CB$ but $AC\neq 0$ (and $CB\neq 0$)?

Comment: Certainly this is happens whenever $A = B = C$.  Are there more requirements here?

Answer (score 1):

For instance, we may take
$$
A = B = C = \pmatrix{
0&1&0\\&0&1\\&&0} \in \Bbb F_q^{3 \times 3}
$$